# how to pass json data as parameter in the http using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services, afnetworking

hi I am trying to pass json request to server.I have use api for that and I have to pass json parameter in my api but I don't know how to pass json parameter in api right know I am using AFNetworking for pass json parameter below code which I have used. Please help me to sort out this problem Thanks in advance..

Parameter format is like

```
 {
  "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
  "phone" : "1234567890",
  "password" : "aaa",
  "medium" : "Email",
  "name" : "abc",
  "uos" : "i"
}
```

code :

```
services *srv=[[services alloc]init];

NSString *str=@"http://emailsending.in/setting_saver_api/";                    NSString *method=@"registration.php";
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dict setObject:self.txtName.text forKey:@"name"];
[dict setObject:self.txtEmail.text forKey:@"email"];
[dict setObject:self.txtphone.text forKey:@"phone"];
[dict setObject:self.txtPassword.text forKey:@"password"];
[dict setObject:@"Email" forKey:@"medium"];
[dict setObject:@"i" forKey:@"uos"];
NSString *jsonString;
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];
if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"json string :%@",jsonString);
}

[srv postToURL:str withMethod:method andParams:jsonString completion:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *responseObj)

 {
     NSLog(@"res :%@",responseObj);
     NSLog(@"%d",success);
     NSLog(@"Successfully..................");
}];
```

Comment: I don't know but the data is not pass to server but i get the converted string in json format which I pass as parameter and I get response is status =0 and msg = data is needed

Comment: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking refer this on github. U will find - JSON Parameter encoding.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error you got. Please contact your backend team.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /setting_saver_api/ was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

And you can use like this:

```
NSString* jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&phone=%@&password=%@&name=%@&uos=%@",email.text,phone.text,password.text,name.text,uos.text];//enter your own values

NSURL *urlPath = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL String"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlPath cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

NSData *requestData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setHTTPBody:requestData];
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {            
                if(data != nil){
                  //your code
                }
                else {
                  //error
                }
}];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi you know how to test this type of api in browser or postman type api testing tool?

Comment: yes @Birendra. I use them frequently. Is your issue solved?

Comment: Once, Yes and it is the best practice to do so @Birendra .

Comment: please give me the response you get?

Comment: please give me the response you get?

Comment: I've posted the response above in my answer. "<!DOCTYPE..." etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103178/discussion-between-satish-a-and-birendra).

Answer (score 0):

Following code may help :

```
NSString *comment_id = @"comment"
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"apiURL];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"apikey":apikey,@"text":text, @"comment_id":comment_id}; // this is an example 

[manager POST:string parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
    NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

    if ([[[data objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"status"] integerValue]){

        //success 

    }else{
        //else part goes here 
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Hi I try above code but get an error NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html}

Comment: contact your server side person .

Comment: you get the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];


    NSDictionary *params = @ {@"user" :txtUserName, @"pwd" :txtPwd };


    [manager POST:URL_SIGNIN parameters:params
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    }
    failure:
     ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
```

Comment: Hi you know how to test this type of api in browser or postman type api testing tool?

Comment: file:///Users/rajeshvishnani/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-11%20at%2012.18.14%20PM.png    i have test api like this is this is correct for the json type parameter?

Comment: and I try you above code but i get an error  NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html}

Comment: http://emailsending.in/setting_saver_api/login.php  and parameter is email and password

Comment: send me the response of your testing

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /setting_saver_api/ was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html> THIS IS RESPONSE CONTACT YOR PHP OR WEBSERVICE TEAM

Comment: url is working you see image which is i send to you?